# Name of signal number 2

Tags: perl

I wondered if there is a module or pragma that defines names for signal numbers as returned by the `system` call? For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd = 'sleep 10';
my $res = system $cmd;
my $signal = $res & 127;
if ( $res == -1 ) {
    die "Failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ( $signal == 2 ) {
    say " Aborted by user.";
}
elsif ( $signal ) {
    printf " Command '%s' Died with signal %d, %s coredump.\n",
      $cmd, $signal, ( $? & 128 ) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
```

Instead of `$signal == 2`, I think for code maintenance, it would be better to use something like `$signal == SIG_ABRT`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is defined in `POSIX` module:

```
% perl -e 'use POSIX; printf "%s\n", SIGABRT;'
6
```

Comment: Thanks.. I think it is SIGINT then?

Comment: Correct, SIGINT is 2 . In Linux, you can list this with `kill -l`.

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of ways to do this. You have seen a method using `POSIX`, which I generally avoid because by default it imports a *huge* number of symbols (nearly six hundred) into the current package. Even if you limit it to the names that you need for this by writing

```
use POSIX ':signal_h';
```

there are still around fifty names imported. It is also a matter of trial and error to discover the *name* of a signal given its *number* using this module.

You could also construct a table of the signals that your Perl was buit with using the [`Config`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config) module, which exports a list of signal names and their corresponding numbers in `$Config{sig_name}` and `$Config{sig_num}`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config '%Config';

my @sig_names;
@sig_names[ split ' ', $Config{sig_num} ] = split ' ', $Config{sig_name};

printf "Signal number 2 is %s\n", $sig_names[2];
```

**output**

```
Signal number 2 is INT
```

Or you can make use of the [`IPC::Signal`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Signal) module which wraps all of this up conveniently

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Signal 'sig_name';

printf "Signal number 2 is %s\n", sig_name(2);
```

**output**

```
Signal number 2 is INT
```

Comment: What about `use POSIX (); my $sigint = POSIX::SIGINT;`. That should avoid importing all symbols also?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: That would work, but you still have to check all `POSIX::SIGXXX` values to find the one you're looking for